# COUNT with LIMIT in mysql query

Tags: mysql, count, limit

i need to get total amount of rows when using LIMIT with my query to avoid twice querying.
is it possible?

Answer (score 14):

Use [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> For a SELECT with a LIMIT clause, the number of rows that would be returned were there no LIMIT clause

use the statement right after your SELECT query, which needs the `CALC_FOUND_ROWS` keyword. Example from the manual:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
```

Note that this puts additional strain on the database, because it has to find out the size of the full result set every time. Use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` only when you need it.