# MySQL/ASP Paging, COUNT with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, asp-classic

I am trying to rebuild my page to go from old-school recordset paging, to LIMIT paging. This will stop my query trying to load 100,000 rows when it really doesn't have to.

The problem I am having, is getting the count of all the records for that search. Before, I was getting the number of results by doing this:

```
recordCount = rsPhotoSearch.RecordCount
```

But now I have limited my query to 30, to show 30 records per page, my 'recordCount' only shows 30, instead of the 100,000 that it should be.

So how am I supposed to get the total number of records for that search, without going through all 100,000 rows, which to me, seems to defy the use of the LIMIT method? I could probably run a separate query, the same, just to count the records - but is that practical, because that will also go though 100,000 rows to get a count?

Any help gratefully received, as usual :)

From confused man

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068018/count-with-limit-in-mysql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to get all rows. Just get the count of everything:

```
select count(*)
from (
    <whatever is your main query goes here, without LIMIT>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input... before I choose an answer, I must test your suggestion against Kul-Tigin's suggestion to see which is faster. By looking at Kul-Tigin's I can get the count and my results from one query whereas yours looks like it will need two queries

Comment: I have tested yours already and it seems pretty quick, I was suprised how quick. I always imagined that (select count(*) from tbl) would perform the same or worse than (select photoID from tbl) but it's obviously a lot quicker

Comment: I'm happy with that. Now it's working, and working fast, I don't see the need to try another solution. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Hi. Create the query with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and then get it via [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function.
What I mean is this:

```vb
Set rsPhotoSearch = _
conn_Object.Execute("Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT offSet, rowCount")
Dim lngTotalRecords
lngTotalRecords = conn_Object.Execute("Select Found_Rows();")(0).Value
Response.Write "Total Records : "& lngTotalRecords 
'Loop starts
'etc
```

Comment: This looks promising. I am not familiar with this format. Instead of (Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table) can I do something like this (Select SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, photoID, dateCreated FROM table)?

Comment: Yes of course but should not be a comma after the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

Answer (score 0):

You quite are correct you will still have to scan your indexes to count the number of rows

I would question how useful showing the number of records is ?

if you calculate the record count yourself (rather than using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`) you can limit the number of rows you scan and improve performance.

Comment: I need to show the user how many photos have been found with their search. I also need to calculate how many pages there will be, so if the user wanted 40 records per page, then I need to do (recordCount/40)

Comment: that was what i was thinking. How useful would it become once you get lots of results....e.g.  page 1 of 3000, would anyone ever user that?

Comment: I understand your point but then how can I work out how many pages there are, to show recordset paging links?

Comment: I guess all you need to know is if there are over page_size*max_number_of_pages records, (then work out how you want to handle the 'next' case) have a look how google does it.